# How to specify an equation is a spreadsheet program like Gnumeric/Excel?

Tags: subtraction, gnumeric

I'm doing a rather repetitive subtraction of  values from column A and column B, in their respective rows, and I don't want to keep on doing, for example, =A1-B1. Is there a way to set the cell for a formula such that I don't have to specify the row but it'll do the subtraction between column A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes-- in the top cell in, say, row c, enter "=A1-B1" and then hover in the corner until you get the plus mark and drag down. That will apply your equation to every cell you drag to.

Answer (score 0):

First Write your formula for the first row.To apply it to the entire column ;Double click the small black square which appears at the bottom right hand corner of the cell