# Add two columns into third column in Gnumeric

Tags: gnumeric

Is there a way to add two columns cell by cell and from a third column? Think of the two columns as two arrays and third column as the sum of these two arrays.

How can I do this in `gnumeric`?

Comment: Ok, This question i've found a similar question and it's solved. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509289/how-to-specify-an-equation-is-a-spreadsheet-program-like-gnumeric-excel?rq=1>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Suppose you want to add data from columns A and B and put the result in column C. Select column C (may be not the whole column though) and type:
=A:A+B:B
then validate using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

If you only need 10 rows, the formula would be
=A1:A10+B1:B10